# JQuery Validation Plugin with CheckBox Group

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I have a number of checkboxes listed on a page, the rendered html is as follows:

I need these grouped checkboxes to use validation so that at least one of the items is checked.

```
<input id="element_frm1167_8_1" name="test" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" validate="required:true, minlength:2">
<input id="element_frm1167_8_2" name="test" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" >
<input id="element_frm1167_8_3" name="test" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" >
```

I've looked at an example from 
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html

However, when I call form.Validate() I dont get any validation happening.

Please could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say that chances are you haven't configured the metadata plugin (or included it at all).  That's what handles taking the `validate` attribute in your checkbox, and turning that into rules for the validation plugin.  To get what you want in a simpler way, you can just specify the rules directly in your validate call:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
 rules: {
    test: {
        required: true,
        minlength:2            
    }
 } 
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/EWbED/

Comment: Thank you Ryley - I hadnt included the metadata plugin correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try with naming your inputs like `name="test[]"` instead of `name="test"`

Comment: I don't see how that would be relevant?  `test` is a legal name for an input isn't it?

Comment: 'test' is legal. The brackets are only needed if posted to a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for folks like me, who find this thread, and want to submit multiple values to PHP after validation (maybe almost everyone?). Include brackets in your form element names

```
<input id="element_frm1167_8_3" name="test[]" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" >
```

and in the validation identifier

```
rules: {
  'test[]': {
    required: true,
    minlength:2            
  }
}
```